# Detecting file type from registry? windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, context-menu

You may have noticed that when right clicking on an exe file (if WinRAR is installed) "Open with WinRAR" option appears only if it's an SFX WinRAR archive. Is there a way for me to add such a command to context menu?

I want to add a context menu item to the directory background called "Extract all", and I need all executable files to be extracted in a subfolder with the same name, but only if they match the file type.

So, I'm looking for a way to check exactly what kind of an executable it actually is. Is it possible with registry keys only?

Comment: @FrankThomas Yes. I know that part. I want to know if I can detect the file type,not by extension or MIME type, but by other means, i.e. read a byte in file header, maybe or by whatever other means there may be, to see whether the executable is an SFX RAR/ZIP/7-ZIP/FreeARC/Whatever and show the item based on that.

Comment: @FrankThomas I see. So, how much leeway is there for to cheat that? i.e. can we use a vb script for that set the command to that vb script? Or, is this question too vague?

Comment: Oh, good, now that the question is posted, SuperUsers bother to show related topics.